# How to split template specialization across different files according to the C++11 standard?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, gcc

I want to implement some integer constants which depend on some other integer constants using template specialization, e.g.

```
//main.cpp
#include<cstdint>

template <uint64_t D> struct space_per_element { static const uint64_t bits; };

template <> const uint64_t space_per_element<2>::bits = 1;

int main() {
    return  space_per_element<2>::bits;
}
```

Which compiles fine using

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

But as soon as I try to split it like this.

```
//constants.hpp
#include<cstdint>

template <uint64_t D> struct space_per_element { static const uint64_t bits; };

//constants.cpp
#include "constants.hpp"

template <> const uint64_t space_per_element<2>::bits = 1;

//main.cpp
#include "constants.hpp"

int main() {
    return  space_per_element<2>::bits;
}
```

And compile it using this.

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp constants.cpp
```

I get the following error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:4:11: error: ‘space_per_element’ was not declared in this scope
   return  space_per_element<2>::bits;
           ^
main.cpp:4:31: error: ‘::bits’ has not been declared
   return  space_per_element<2>::bits;
                               ^
constants.cpp:3:45: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
 template <> const uint64_t space_per_element<2>::bits = 1;
```

Funnily enough, the code works with

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 main.cpp constants.cpp
```

or

```
clang -std=c++11 main.cpp constants.cpp
```

My questions now are: Which GNU-extension is used here? Is the code violating the standard? If yes: how do I implement this code in multiple files only using the standard? Would it be considered bad practice (from a portability point of view) to use `GNU++11` if Clang seems to support the same code?

Comment: You have to *declare* the specialization in header.

Comment: Originally I had the content of `constants.cpp` in `constants.hpp`. This solves the `expected initializer...` error, but the errors in `main.cpp` remain.

Comment: Was that an attempt to answer @Jarod42's point?  It does not seem to.

Comment: @Yakk: yeah I forgot the @Jarod42.
@Jarod42: declaring the specializations in the header (as in `constants.cpp`, only without the include) does unfortunately not solve the problem.

Comment: @user1512263 You aren't making sense.  Can you please edit what you mean, as an example of code, into the question?  Ideally include compiler versions as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there were some precompiled headers, which did not fit together with the other code, in the same directory. After I deleted them (`rm *.gch`), I was able to compile the files using `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp constants.cpp`.

So it seems, that the two working options worked, because they did not use these precompiled headers.